# Access denied using Py2exe

Tags: python, windows-services, py2exe

I'm using Py2exe to create an executable as a windows service.

When I run the script I get this error:

> File "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\582d895bd5b431ac\winpython\WinPython-32bit-2.7.3.3\python-2.7.3\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 860, in build_executable
>      **add_resource(ensure_unicode(exe_path), script_bytes, u"PYTHONSCRIPT", 1, True)
>   RuntimeError: EndUpdateResource: Access is denied.**

This is the call to py2exe:

```
    setup(
    name = NAME,
    description = DESCRIPTION,
    version = '1.0.133.43',
    service = [{'modules':["ServiceLauncher"], 'cmdline':'pywin32'}],
    zipfile=None,
    options = {
        "py2exe":{"packages":"encodings",
                  "includes":"win32com,win32service,win32serviceutil,win32event",
                  "excludes":"libiomp5md.dll"
        },
        },
    )
```

The problem occurs only on the build machine, it runs fine on my dev pc.

I've tried to set Full Control to everyone on the work folder, but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, try a shorter path-name if possible. Weird bugs can occur when the path is to long in Windows.

Comment: The error might not be access to a particular file on the filesystem, but to some other feature, like a registry key or a service manager setting (since I notice you're using `ServiceLauncher`, `win32service`, etc.…). Are you running as admin?

Comment: I'm running as Administrator.
I've tried a shorter path with no luck...

Comment: How can I check if it is a problem related to registry or service manager?

Comment: Could check your AUTH log in the "Event Viewer", might get lucky.

Comment: No luck with the event viewer...

Comment: The simple approach is then to just remove one `includes` at a time, and see whichever fails first. Just to narrow things down.

Comment: I've tried removing the includes, adding only one at a time.
Also removed packages and exclude. Same error!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After two days investigating we found a solution with the help of the IT staff.

The issue arise when py2exe try to modify the executable adding metadata and\or icon.

The root cause? Simple... ANTIVIRUS.

It considers that operation a threat and cause the Access Denied error.

Thank you all!

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I had the same problem, googled it, came across this answer, disabled antivirus, hit run again, and all was good. Total time elapsed: 1 min. Probably saved me hours!

Comment: In case you cannot disable antivirus, running the build process (py2exe) twice may help. It worked for me because first time it built library.zip and failed. Second time, it was able build the  executable.

Comment: @syam Thanks for mentioning this =)

Comment: perfect answer! As my AV didnt popup any warning/error, I wouldnt have thought of this any time soon

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely an antivirus program blocking write access to .exe files as others have noted. If you cannot or do not want to disable antivirus the following patch at the beginning of your `setup.py` file will rename the file to avoid the `.exe` extension before the modification and rename it back after.

```py
import py2exe.py2exe_util
from py2exe.py2exe_util import add_resource
import os

def add_resource_patch(name, *arg, **kwarg):
    name_tmp = name + '.tmp'
    os.rename(name, name_tmp)
    add_resource(name_tmp, *arg, **kwarg)
    os.rename(name_tmp, name)

py2exe.py2exe_util.add_resource = add_resource_patch

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(...)
```

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else did.  It is also good because it permanently patches the problem and removes the Pause and Unpause Steps from my process flow.

Answer (score 1):

I found that disconnecting from the Internet was enough to solve the problem (though this is probably related to the disabling the antivirus solution proposed).

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution is that you already have a dist folder with files in it - i did (forgot i had already run py2exe). removed the folder and it worked again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11012129)

Comment: @FabioLamanna I ran into a similar problem as the author, and this is a solution that worked for me. for others that might end up in my shoes, this is a good resource to have if they come across this post.

Answer (score 0):

May be an issue if you use a folder under `C:\Users`. Windows apparently does not like it. Just run `pyinstaller` from another folder (after moving your files to that other folder). I moved my python scripts under `C:\Temp` and it worked like a charm where under `C:\Users`, I had the same permission issue (even when the `cmd` running as admin user).