# Py2exe. RuntimeError: EndUpdateResourse: "Access is denied"

Tags: python

I have a problem that was discussed in 
[this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848033/access-denied-using-py2exe)
I try to build a programm with py2exe, but have an errors EndUpdateResource type:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "py2exe_setup.py", line 160, in module
>   ]+matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles()
>
> File "C:\Python25\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
>   dist.run_commands()
>
> File "C:\Python25\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_commands
>   self.run_commands()
>
> File "C:\Python25\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 994, in run_command
>   cmd_obj.run()
>
> File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in
>   run self._run()
>
> File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 312, in
>   _run self.create_binaries(py_files,extensions,dlls)
>
> File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 568, in
>   create_binaries arcname,target.script)
>
> File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 860, in
>   build_executable add_resource(ensure_unicode(exe_path),script_bytes,
>   u"PYTHONSCRIPT",1,True)
>
> RuntimeError: EndUpdateResource:  ╬Єърчрэю т фюёЄєях.

I'm just guessing, that after "EndUpdateResource" follows "Access is denied" ("Отказано в доступе." in russian, something with encoding)

The folk say that this is all antivirus falt. But I disabled the antivirus. It did not help. 
I'm in system as an administrator. Have no ideas. Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied using Py2exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848033/access-denied-using-py2exe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antivirus still was running as service. Stopped it and all worked.

Answer (score 2):

Running py2exe twice helps. In my case, it worked the second time I ran and was able to build the exe. However, have not found the reason why this happens.

Comment: hard to believe on this solution, but yes, for me also this solution works.