# Eliminate "<APP_NAME> would like to access your photos." prompt when building native macOS app with py2app and wxPython

Tags: macos, wxpython, py2app, appstore-sandbox

I am building a native macOS application from a Python program that uses wxPython (and ultimately wxWidgets) to present a GUI using py2app. However when I start the built .app, I get a permission prompt that says "<APP_NAME> would like to access your photos." However my app really has no special interest in the Photos directory. How do I get rid of this prompt?

[image]

In case it's useful, I'm testing on macOS 10.14 (Mojave).

Comment: This is clearly an OS permissions issue, not a coding problem.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Could you describe what you mean by an "OS permissions issue"?

Comment: Precisely what I said. Clearly, some access/security component on your Mac is keeping an eye on what is accessing what.  That message isn't coming out of your code or wxpython, so it looks like you might have to configure something else on your system to whitelist what you're attempting to do.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848033/access-denied-using-py2exe could be the issue

Comment: Nope. That's py2exe on Windows. This prompt is Mac-specific, related to py2app, and raised by the operating system itself rather than 3rd party software. I know this because this type of dialog was raised for a large number of (non-Python) native apps after a major OS upgrade.

Comment: In other words, you're confirming my original contention. It's not a coding issue. So this question would be better served in a different forum.